# How to include different php file depend on screen resolution

Tags: jquery, wordpress, responsive-design

Im working on responsive site in Wordpress.

I want to display totaly different pictures in my slider for mobile devices.

I come up to idea to make 2 different jquery sliders, place them in 2 php files and load them according to specific screen resolution.

How can I load (include) php file on the fly with javascript/jquery?
I found sth like:

```
 if (screen.width >= 720 ) 
 $('#place_holder_div').load('file_from_server.php');
```

But it doesnt seem to work...

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: the content from the php file is not loaded. Ive try to locate it in template folder as well as wordpress main folder.

Comment: Try loading the URL manually in your browser and see what happens. The JS looks fine, so it is likely either a bad URL or server error.

Comment: I've manage to make it work by adding $(document).ready(function()... But still have a problem cause the content is loading wherever resolution is biger than 720 or smaller...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`wp_is_mobile()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile).

It returns `true` / `false`. So simply check to see if you're on a mobile device and then conditionally include the slider you want.